# Hibernate Criteria Query is adding an extra order by clause

Tags: hibernate

I have a DetachedCriteria query with projection and transformer as given below

```
criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Report.class, "r");
criteria
.createAlias("template", "t")
.createAlias("constituents", "c")
.setProjection(
        Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("r.reportId").as("reportId"))
.add(Projections.property("r.reportNm").as("reportNm"))
.add(Projections.property("t.templateNm").as("templateNm"))
.add(Projections.property("t.templateTyp").as("templateTyp"))
).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ReportSummary.class));
```

I then get Citeria from session and now when I try to add orderBy clause dynamically, i.e.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Criteria c = criteria.getExecutableCriteria(session);
Order order = sortDirection.equals("ASC")?
Order.asc(orderByColumnName):Order.desc(orderByColumnName);
c.addOrder(order);
```

the generated query contains an extra orderBy clause i.e.

```
order by reportId ASC(NOT REQUIRED ADDED AUTOMATICALLY), order by reportNm ASC
```

Can someone please guide me to a solution